# Running a Array of Objects outside render function

Tags: arrays, reactjs, javascript-objects

Either fails to compile defining variables inside `componentDidMount`. I did a bunch of dozens of other ways. None seems to work for my particular piece of code. I think reading is better than trying to explain.

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from './api';
import './App.css';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      giphy: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    connect(message => {
      this.setState({
        giphy: message
      })
    });
    var Items = this.state.giphy.map(function(gif){ // items is not defined.
      return <li>{gif}</li>;
    })
  }

  render () {
      return (
        <div className=".App-logo">
            <ul>
              { Items } // I wanted to show all items inside the array of objects.
            </ul>

            <ul className=".App-logo"> 
            // the following method works. We need to make sure to check for this conditions or wont work
              {this.state.giphy && this.state.giphy.length > 0   &&
                <img src={ this.state.giphy[2].images.original.url}
                alt="giphy.com animations"/>}
            </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

If I remove the items, it will show the 2nd item in the state.
Can you help to show all in the state?

[image]

Comment: You need to use the callback on setState, your array is not populated. `setState({}, () => { map state here}).

Comment: Hi staminna, check my solution and let me know if tha helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating a variable in `componentDidMount` which cannot be used inside of `render` method, you can directly `map` your state in `render` method.

```
<ul>
   //This will show only `bitly_gif_url`
   {Array.isArray(this.state.giphy) && this.state.giphy.map(gif => <li>{gif.bitly_gif_url}</li>) } 
</ul>
```

**Note:** Your `giphy` array contains number of objects. From each object I have shown only `bitly_gif_url` using `{gif.bitly_gif_url}`, if you need to show any other item from your object you can change it's key.

You can show mutltiple item's at a time also,

```
<ul>
   //This will show `bitly_gif_url` and `embed_url` at a time
   {Array.isArray(this.state.giphy) && this.state.giphy.map(gif => <li>{gif.bitly_gif_url} {gif.embed_url}</li>) } 
</ul>
```

Comment: @DanielSmith, sure will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

As you have defined Items inside your componentDidMount function it have a functional scope and will not be available inside render function what you can do is return the items from a function. So now your code will look something like

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from './api';
import './App.css';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      giphy: []
    }

  }

  componentDidMount(){
    connect(message => {
      this.setState({
        giphy: message
      })
    });
  }

  getItems() {
    return this.state.giphy.map(function(gif){
      return <li>{gif}</li>;
    })
  }

  render () {
      return (
        <div className=".App-logo">
            <ul>
              { this.getItems() } // I wanted to show all items inside the array of objects.
            </ul>

            <ul className=".App-logo"> 
            // the following method works. We need to make sure to check for this conditions or wont work
              {this.state.giphy && this.state.giphy.length > 0   &&
                <img src={ this.state.giphy[2].images.original.url}
                alt="giphy.com animations"/>}
            </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {type, id, slug, url, bitly_gif_url, bitly_url, embed_url, username, images}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: as gif inside the map function is an object you need to replace {gif} with {<img src={gif.embed_url} />} i guess you get the gist.